# Accessing Parent Chart from it's Embedded Excel

Tags: excel, vba, oop, excel-charts

This might be a question stemming from ignorance of OOPS concepts, but I was wondering, is it possible to work one's way backwards and reach the parent object.

```
'To access the embedded workbook of a Powerpoint Chart, one can use this line of code
    
          Dim EmbdWbk 
          Set EmbdWbk= ThisShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook
    
'Similarly can one use something like the below code to reach the chart
    
          Dim myChart as Chart
          Set myChart = EmbdWbk.Parent.Parent.Parent  

'As you can see from the immediate window snap below, this just takes me 
'directly to the Application bypassing the Chart and Shape.
'So is there a way this can happen ?
```

[image]

Comment: But what are your expectations? Which to be the `Parent` of a `Workbook`? What does `Debug.Print Embdwbk.Parent.Name` return in `Immediate Window`?

Comment: It is giving me the output as `Microsoft Excel`. My expectation is to somehow access the chart from the workbook, going backwards.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. Since you obtained the workbook object **as a chart `Parent`**, the chart in discussion is a child of this object. Its `Parent` obviously is `Excel Application`. There is no any direct way to return such a `child`, since a workbook has many. It has only a single `Parent` which correctly has been returned...

Comment: Just curious do other languages can handle such things ?

Comment: No, they cannot, too. The `Parent` property is not something like a 'two-way` definition. Like you have your parents and you are their child, if you ask about their parents, you cannot be returned. Asking about parent(s), only your grandfather/grandmother can be returned by any `intelligent` application. For instance, a Windows window my have many child windows. Using one of its child windows, the parent can be **directly** returned, but viceversa can be done only searching for a specific characteristic (class, title) in its children windows collection...